# In-page form does not send data to remotely hosted aspx form

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, linked-list

I have an html form with the action linking to a remotely hosted aspx form. The html form mimics all the input names, ids, values, etc. of the aspx form.

After submitting the html login form with correct login data, instead of processing the data and redirecting to the target link, the page links to the raw login form with only the username data entered. Upon filling in the correct information again, the user is able to log in.

By checking the function of the other instances of the same login form on the site and encountering the same problem, I surmised that the issue is inherent in the remote aspx file, not the html form.

The form was working until about a week ago, when it promptly started behaving like this without any changes made to the code.

The live site is at http://blinqphoto.com

Thank you for any responses, this has me stumped.
Please find the html form and corresponding aspx form below.

HTML:

```
<form style="" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="https://acct.blinqphoto.com/loginframe.aspxredirect=http%3a%2f%2fwww.blinqphoto.com%2fmy-albums%2f" id="LoginForm">

<div>
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMjU0ODEwOTIzZGR61068oyJyEBB4UM9Gc8Fxx4225NLn2XmKWX95/vl6Zg==" type="hidden">
</div>

<div>
<input name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"value="/wEWBAL1/8vwCgKTqJrlAQKN8oRJAv6M0J8PQkj11RCPtUGzghOj3yic+Mr17E559GJ73UVSHbxO9VE=" type="hidden">
</div>

<span> Email <input name="UserNameTxt" id="UserNameTxt" placeholder="example@gmail.com" type="text"></span>
<br>

<span>Password<input name="PasswordTxt" id="PasswordTxt" placeholder="password" class="password" type="password"></span>
<br>

<input name="LoginButton" value="Sign in" class="LoginButton" type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

aspx:

```
<form style="" name="LoginForm" method="post"    action="https://acct.blinqphoto.com/loginframe.aspx?redirect=http%3a%2f%2fwww.blinqphoto.com%2fmy-albums%2f" id="LoginForm">

<div>
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMjU0ODEwOTIzZGR61068oyJyEBB4UM9Gc8Fxx4225NLn2XmKWX95/vl6Zg==" type="hidden">
</div>

<div>
<input name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBAL1/8vwCgKTqJrlAQKN8oRJAv6M0J8PQkj11RCPtUGzghOj3yic+Mr17E559GJ73UVSHbxO9VE=" type="hidden">
</div>

<span> Email <input name="UserNameTxt" id="UserNameTxt" placeholder="example@gmail.com" type="text"></span>
<br>

 <span>Password<input name="PasswordTxt" id="PasswordTxt" placeholder="password" class="password" type="password"></span>
<br> 

<input name="LoginButton" value="Sign in" class="LoginButton" type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Aren't HTML and aspx the same?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the .NET event validation.  If you look closely, the value of the __EVENTVALIDATION form field is not always exactly the same.  This is used to validate the postback - to check that it is not coming from another URL for example, which is exactly what you are doing.

You need to disable the event validation for the login.aspx page.

```
Page.EnableEventValidation   = false;
```

[Is there a way to disable Event Validation for an entire page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669301/is-there-a-way-to-disable-event-validation-for-an-entire-page)

Note that disable event validation can possibly make your page more vulnerable.